# How can I make correct xml api request?

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, guzzle

I am integrating Rkiper using the xml interface. I faced such a problem that through postman my request quietly leaves and I get the answer I need, but using the script I can't do it.

I wrote the following code:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
$client = new Client([ 'verify' => false]);
//
$uri = 'https://95.78.120.27:8096/rk7api/v0/xmlinterface.xml';
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<RK7Query>
<RK7CMD CMD="GetRefList"/>
</RK7Query>';
$request = new Request(
  'POST', 
  $uri,
  ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF8',
  'Authorization' => 'Basic xxx'],
  $xml
);
$response = $client->send($request);
echo $response->getBody();
```

In this case, I get just an empty response, a white page.
You might think that there is something with authorization (instead of the password xxx put), but no, this is not so, because otherwise it will display 401 unauthorize. It is enough for us to change the sent xml so that it cannot steam out, then in the response we will already receive

```
   [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException] 
Server error: `POST https://95.78.120.27:8096/rk7api/v0/xmlinterface.xml` resulted in a `500 Unable to do action` response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<messagesData>
    <type>SimpleXMLException</type>
    <mesg>&quot;RK7CMD&quot; expe (truncated...)
 (500)
```

You might think that the problem is on the xml side of the interface with which I communicate, but no, through postman I get correct answer.

Postman generated such a curl request, but even if you put it in a script and run it, there will also be a white screen:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://95.78.120.27:8096/rk7api/v0/xmlinterface.xml",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"\t<RK7Query>\n\t<RK7CMD CMD=\"GetRefList\"/>\n\t</RK7Query>'",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic SFRUUFVzZXI6eih5K040aUhhY3Uw",
    "Content-Type: application/xml"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

In general, I've been sitting at this stage for about a week and don't understand what my problem is. Help me please :)

Comment: Not sure how critical that password is, but you should probably change it now that you posted it.